# How does the solution of ODE $y'=F(t,y)$ extend to an open interval?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I'm trying to solve the above problem from Taylor's PDE I, and I'm supposed to use compactness of $K$. But how does it work?

[image]

Comment: Well loosely speaking the Lipschitz condition comes in when you are trying to extend the interval of the solution; there is no point in extending the interval of the solution if you don't know there exists one (: Now the only thing available to you is the compactness of $K$, so pretty much the only thing you can do is to use that to prove the statement. Hint: what is the definition of $K$ being compact?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how to use the definition to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first motivate why do you need compactness for the statement. Essentially, what the Fundamental theorem tells us is that if F is locally Lipschitz on an open subset $U$, then for any points $y\in U$, you can find a neighbourhood $V$ of $y$ and a time $\tau$ such that there exists a unique solution for every initial condition $y_0$ in $V$. So, all these neighbourhoods will form a cover of $U$ (in particular $K$), and here is where compactness comes in: the **finiteness** of the subcover will then allow you to extend the interval. Note that you also need to assume your solution stays in the compact set $K$, otherwise your solution will cease to exist.

***Proof:*** By the Fundamental theorem, for all $y\in K$, there exists an open neighbourhood $V_y$ of y and a time $\tau_y$ such that the solution is defined for all initial condition $y_0\in V_y$ and $|t|\le\tau_y$. The set $\{V_y\colon y\in K\}$ form an open cover of K, so by compactness of K, there exists a finite subcover $\{V_{y_j}:j=1,\ldots,n\}$. Define $\tau$ to be $\min_j\tau_{y_j}$, then $\forall y_0\in K$, the solution $y(t)$ exists for $|t|\le\tau$. But since we assume $y(t)\in K$ for $t\in[T_0,T_1]$, then $y(t)$ is defined for at least $t\in[T_0-\tau,T_1+\tau]$.

> As a Corollary, if there exists a compact subset $K$ such that once inside $K$, the solutions can't leave it, then those solutions are defined for all $t>0$.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer!